# Errors in Default Blank Activity - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I installed android studio, launched it, opened a new project with a blank activity and there are three errors in MainActivity.java. I might have installed it incorrectly. How can I completely uninstall Android Studio, the SDK, and the JDK to reinstall? Or is there some other fix I should do that I'm unaware of?

The code I have is:

```
package com.francesco.musica;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

findViewById on line 18, findViewById on line 21, and onOptionsItemSelected on line 50 are all underlined with the error Cannot resolve method '...'

Should I completely uninstall and reinstall everything or is there another way to get my Android Studio to work normally?

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: try cleaning the project.

Comment: Clean and then make your project. Its a studio bug. Happens  sometimes. Be patient. Check your layouts so that you can find out what really causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you wait for the gradle to build the project completely? It sometimes takes a while for the project to build, and shows errors whilst building.

Try creating a new project, rather than uninstalling and reinstalling all of Android Studios. Or you can try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Cleaned project and I'm back at square one. Nothing is loading on the bar at the bottom so I'm sure it's all loaded. I started a new project and a popup saying IDE Internal Error occurred came up. After Gradle build finished I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Have you checked for any updates? If not, do that. Otherwise, it'll probably be better uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio, android sdk, and java jdk a couple times and it's never worked. What is the best way to completely uninstall everything?

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uninstallreinstall-android-studio this might help

Answer (score 0):

Updated to latest canary build and everything worked out. Strange how what is supposed to be the less stable build managed to work out better for me. Glad I'm finally up and running!